# UITableViewCell customization - change background

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4

I'm sure this is a question that been asked and answered, but I can't seem to find what I need. I am trying to customize the background of my UITableView, so to do this, I created a subclass of UITableViewCell, and built my custom cell with the IB. I successfully connected the custom cell to the table view, so the cell I get is getting displayed. I am trying to change the background of each cell, so here is what I use:

```
if(row == 1){
    rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"VehicleExpenses_button.png"];
    selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"VehicleExpenses_button_selected.png"];
    ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = rowBackground;
  //  ((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = selectionBackground;
}
```

within the

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method of my Controller class. I checked with the debugger, and all the lines in the code are getting called...

Any ideas?

This is the entire method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"HomeViewCell";
    static NSString *CellNib = @"HomeViewCell";

    UIImage *rowBackground;
    UIImage *selectionBackground;

    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];


    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if(row == 1){

        rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"VehicleExpenses_button.png"];
        selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"VehicleExpenses_button_selected.png"];
        ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = rowBackground;
      //  ((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = selectionBackground;
    }

    // perform additional custom work...

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong but I don't see where you initialized the backgroundView as a UIImageView. Here is what I would add to the lines where you create the cells:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, tableView.bounds.size.width, cellHeight)] autorelease];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, tableView.bounds.size.width, cellHeight)] autorelease];
    }
```

Note: replace "cellHeight" with your desired height.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried doing this code above, and it didn't work...would there be any possible connections I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related, but every time I access tableView, for instance in tableView.bounds.size.width, I get a warning that says "Local declaration of 'tableView' hides instance variable'

Comment: @Heather: That means you called the tableview object in your .h file "tableView." That's an issue, because the method has a local variable with the exact name... the compiler doesn't know which you are referring to.

Comment: @Heather: not sure why the images aren't showing... are you sure the png images are in the project folder? Can you edit the other properties of the cell (e.g. set some text to see if it renders)? I noticed you're trying to set the background on row==1... that's the second row... is that what you're looking for? Just trying to think of everything here.

Comment: I got rid of the instance of tableView in my .h file. I had connected it from the IB to the UITableView I have so I could set the row height. I tried rerunning the code, and the second row is still not changing.

Comment: The png images are definitely in the project folder. I took your advice, and tried to add some text to the second cell, and it worked fine...I used cell.textLabel.text = @"hi". I do want background changing in the second cell. The idea is the first cell background is set in the IB, and the second it changed in the code.

Comment: It's probably still good to have some reference to the tableview linked from IB to your view controller, but I just wouldn't name it "tableView" due to the delegate/datasource methods. Are you sure that method is being called? Are you sure you set the delegate and the datasource of the tableview to the file's owner in IB?

Comment: The method is definitely being called. I have checked this with the debugger, also when I added the text it worked. I just checked again, and the delegate and datasource of the table is set to the file's owner

Comment: @Heather: I don't know what to say... I just created a sample project with just a tableview, used the lines in my answer and set the background image using the icon image... everything worked. Try a different image?? Like the icon image??

Comment: I tried it with a different image and it didn't work. Just to make sure...I have already set the image using the IB, and I am trying to change it based on the row...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
UIImageView *cellBackGround = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedRow.png"]];
[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setBackgroundView:cellBackGround];
[cellBackGround release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Small problem. Instead of casting and setting the `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView`'s image property, set them to the `UIImageView` created from your images.

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:rowBackground] autorelease];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:selectionBackground] autorelease];
```

Comment: I just tried this, and still no luck. I should be changing the background of the cell in the view controller, not the custom UITableViewCell class, correct?

Comment: @Heather: Yes, change the background of the cell in the controller. What you're attempting in your example is the correct/popular way of doing it... see my answer; it might help.